# How to rotate function around x axis

Tags: calculus, integration

The problem is:

Revolve the function around the $x-$axis, then find the volume enclosed by the $3D$ shape from $x_1=0$ to $x_2=16$.

The following formula may be used to determine the volume of the solid:

$$\displaystyle V=\int_{x_1}^{x_2} \pi[f(x)]^2dx$$

The function is as follows:

$$f(x)= \dfrac{6.4}{x+12} \sin\left(\dfrac{2~\pi}{6.5}x\right)+3$$

My question is:

a) What would the resulting function be?

And more importantly,

b) How would I convert this into a $3D$ function, that is, incorporate $z$ so it can be graphed in $3D$?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equation for the volume is correct. However, actually plotting the volume is somewhat more complicated. Specifically, in 3D space you need a matrix of terms for each of $x, y$, and $z$. This is most easily visualized in a vertical arrangement, with rotation about the $z$-axis. So imagine the line $r=f(z)$. Then take a vector $\theta\in[0,2\pi]$ with however many points you wish and for each value of $z$ find $X=r\cos\theta$, $Y=r\sin\theta$. These are matrices of the size of $r$ by the size of $\theta$. The $Z$ matrix is just a uniformly spaced matrix for all the $z$ and $\theta$ values. Many computer languages have such functions built in. I used Matlab's *cylinder* function to create the figure below.

EDIT: At the request of the OP, I am adding the Matlab code. Note that function *cylinder* is a Matlab built-in function described [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cylinder.html?searchHighlight=cylinder&s_tid=doc_srchtitle).

```
x=16*linspace(0,1,4001)';
f=6.4./(x+12).*sin(2*pi*x/6.5)+3;

[X,Y,Z]=cylinder(f,50);

figure;surf(X,Y,16*Z)
axis equal
shading flat
xlabel('X');ylabel('Z');zlabel('Y','Rotation',0)
```

[image: 3D volume for $f(x)$]

Comment: Do you mind sharing the matlab code?

Comment: @user3551274 I don't mind sharing my code at all. See the edited version of my post.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the curve $y = f(x)$ is drawn in the $(x, y)$ plane and that this graph is rotated around the $x$ axis in 3D, it creates a surface which equation is $y^2+z^2 = f^2(x)$, or $z = \pm \sqrt{f^2(x) - y^2}$

Edit: After Cye Waldman awesome picture, I'll add my own picture, obtained with python with modules numpy and matplotlib, with source code

[image]

Here is the python code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d as axes3d

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection='3d')

u = np.linspace(0, 16, 60)
v = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 60)
U, V = np.meshgrid(u, v)

X = U
F = (6.4/(U+12.0))* np.sin(2*np.pi*U/6.5) + 3.0
Y = F*np.cos(V)
Z = F*np.sin(V)

ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, alpha=0.3, color='red', rstride=6, cstride=12)
plt.savefig('surface.png')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Nice job. I see that you understand the problem in spite of the awkward equation that suggests, to me, anyway, that $z=0$.